# C language how to remove or not show rows with 0 value column

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, 2d

for example, we have this

```
0 1 0 1
0 3 1 0
0 1 5 0
0 0 0 0
```

matrix I want to show just rows and columns with non zero elements
the final matrix view should be this

```
1 0 1
3 1 0
1 5 0
```

how can I remove the row and the columns with zero elements
my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[100],row,col,i,j,count=0,k=0;
    scanf("%d %d", &row, &col);
    int matrix[row][col];
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j]==0)
            {
                count++;    
            }
        }
    }
            for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
                {
                        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
                        {
                            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
                        }
                    printf("\n");
                }

}

return 0;   
}
```

what condition should I set for count++ I'm new in c developing staff.

Comment: Why even use a counter ? Simply move the condition to the printing loop, and flip it(Not)

Comment: Did you code compile? I believe there's an extra `}`.

Comment: To achieve what you want, you'll have to proceed in at least 2 passes. 1. have some `display_row` array variable which should be set not to `0` if at least one value in the row is not `0`. 2. second pass: display the matrix only where `display_row[i]` is not `0`.

Comment: @sagi I did it but that just handle full zero 0 row thanks for full zero column what condition I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Judge if each rows and columns should be shown.
2. Print only rows and columns that should be shown.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int row,col,i,j;

    // read the matrix
    if (scanf("%d %d", &row, &col) != 2)
    {
        fputs("read error\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    int matrix[row][col];
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]) != 1)
            {
                fputs("read error\n", stderr);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // judge if each rows should be shown
    int show_row[row];
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        show_row[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j]!=0)
            {
                // non-zero element found, so this row should  be shown
                show_row[i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // judge if each columns should be shown
    int show_col[col];
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        show_col[j] = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j]!=0)
            {
                // non-zero element found, so this column should be shown
                show_col[j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    // show rows and columns that should be shown
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        if (show_row[i])
        {
            for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
            {
                if (show_col[j])
                {
                    printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: `show_row[i] = 1;`--> `show_row[i] = 1; break;` (and likewise for the column-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Transpose the matrix ignoring rows with all zeros into a new matrix.
Transpose the new matrix ignoring all-zero rows into a second new matrix.
Print the second matrix.

```
int m1[4][4], m2[4][4], m[4][4] = {
    {0, 1, 0, 1},
    {0, 3, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 5, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
};
transpose_notzero(m1, m);  // m1 = T(m);  ignore all-zero rows
transpose_notzero(m2, m1); // m2 = T(m1); ignore all-zero rows
mat_print(m2);
```

Comment: Where is the implementation of `transpose_notzero` and `mat_print`? How will the functions recognize the size of the matrix?

Comment: Those implementation detais are left to the OP :-) He can wrap the matrix inside a struct, for example: `struct Matrix { int data[MAXROWS][MAXCOLS]; int rows, int cols; };`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the loop where you count the number of elements being equal to zero, you could register which rows/columns that contains **non-zero** values.

Like:

```
int non_zero_row[row];
int non_zero_col[col];
memset(non_zero_row, 0, row * sizeof non_zero_row[0]);  // Set to zero, i.e. expect
memset(non_zero_col, 0, col * sizeof non_zero_col[0]);  // that the row/col is all-zero

for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        if(matrix[i][j] != 0)
        {
            non_zero_row[i] = 1;  // Mark row as containing a non-zero value
            non_zero_col[j] = 1;  // Mark row as containing a non-zero value
        }
    }
}
```

Later in the code you can use the two "boolean" arrays to determine what to do with the element. Something like:

```
if (non_zero_row[i] && non_zero_col[j])
{
    // Do something with element [i][j], e.g. print it
}
```

In principle you don't need to calculate the "boolean" arrays in a separate loop. You could update the "boolean" arrays just after `scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j])` and thereby avoid an extra loop.

BTW: Be careful with VLAs. Your current code doesn't check the array dimensions before creating the matrix. Users of your program can enter big values which may result in stack overflow.